# how to cast a char array to compare it with unsigned char array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to cast s2 to make the test pass.

I store printable characters together with unsigned char values into s3.

s2 is a test string result meant to verify printable char are loaded properly in s3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define test_string_len 2

union {
    char unsigned us[test_string_len];
    char          s1[test_string_len];  
} result;

main() {

    char *s2;
    s2=  "ab";         

    char unsigned s3[test_string_len];          
    s3[0] = 'a';
    s3[1] = 'b';    
    s3[2] = '\0';   

    memcpy (result.us, s3, test_string_len);                

    if ( result.s1 == s2)    {

            printf("Pass\n");
    }

    printf("s2 = %s\n", s2 );
    printf("s3 = %s\n", s3 );   
    printf("result.s1 = %s\n", s3 );
    printf("result.us = %s\n", result.us );

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `test_string_len` should be `3`, you need the two bytes for the string as well as the null character at the end `\0`. That isn't your problem but would make your code 'more correct'.

Comment: If you're just trying to get functions to stop complaining about issues of signed vs unsigned chars, you're probably looking for a cast `(char*)` instead of a union.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to compare strings (or other arrays) with `==` in C. This is because an array such as `int myarray[8];` can essentially be thought of as a pointer called `myarray` storing the address of the *first* element. In other words, `==` would compare the *starting address* of the array, rather than the *contents* of the actual array items being pointed to.

Instead, you must either use the [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) or [memcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcmp.html) functions, or use a `for()` loop to cycle through each index and check that the values in each array match.

Comment: Thanks so much. I get a pass with

   *result.s1 == *s2

is this considered a bad coding practice ?

Comment: That's equivalent to `result.s1[0] == s2[0]` i.e. it's only comparing the first characters of each string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code as follows.

```
 if(!strcmp( result.s1,s2))    {

            printf("Pass\n");
    }
```